# how to create links for all files in directory with javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, cordova, hyperlink

I have such list but with lists all contents in a directory but I want to create a link to also if you click into the file it'll read the file if it's a directory then it'll go into the directory..

```
e.g. the list is
a (folder)
b (folder)
c (folder)
d (folder)
e (folder)
f (folder)
asdf.txt
asdf.html
asdf.ini
```

and if I clic on folder a then it'll go into the a directory if I click on asdf.txt then it'll show what's in the txt.

I have the following code to create all the contents but not sure how to implement links into all directories and files

```
for(var I in entries)
{
    // creates li and /li
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    // creates the name of the contents
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entries[I].name));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is actually what I tried but didn't work so I just delete it and posted my original.....guess I should post this too

```
    var ul = document.getElementById('contentList');
    // for all the entries inside the directory loop the following
    for(var I in entries)
    {
        // creates li and /li
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        // creates the name of the contents

        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(a);
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entries[I].name));
        a.href = (entries[I].name);
        li.appendChild(a);
        ul.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: is it that hard to figure out how to include `<a>` into what you have?

Comment: DomI> ya I know...I saw that post but somehow it didn't work

Comment: charliefl> it's not hard to try that but somehow it didn't work so I'm like @_@

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just a matter of  `li.appendChild('<a href="…">' + entries[I].name + '</a>'));` or is the challenge to create differentiate links to files and folders?

Comment: yes differentiate links....I remember it wasn't so hard with php and I believe they work the same where `a href="$variableOfTheFileName"` but doesn't seem to work O.o

Comment: So is that the PHP you trying to get them to work in or in JavaScript? It would be easier if you post the code that generates the list of files and folders and the code that renders HTML.

Comment: oh in PHP but I thought they might work pretty much simliar I'm really bad with javascript but I want the code to work in javascript